# Test Kitchen is Broken on Ubuntu 18.04 Because of Rspec Mismatch

Tags: rspec, test-kitchen, serverspec

I've run tests in the same environment for weeks now without issues. Just today I started getting errors:

```
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby -I/tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec -I/tmp/verifier/gems/gems/rspec-support-3.9.0/lib:/tmp/verifier/gems/gems/rspec-core-3.9.0/lib /opt/chef/embedded/bin/rspec --pattern /tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec/\*\*/\*_spec.rb --color --format documentation --default-path /tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec

Failure/Error: raise Gem::ConflictError.new self, conflicts

Gem::ConflictError:
   Unable to activate rspec-3.8.0, because rspec-core-3.9.0 conflicts with rspec-core (~> 3.8.0)
```

I'm using busser-serverspec for serverspec tests. rspec-core-3.9.0 and rspec-support-3.9.0 are being installed along with busser-serverspec. I've tried overriding this with a Gemfile under `test/integration/default/serverspec/` but nothing I do is resolving this for me.

How can I force kitchen and/or busser-serverspec to NOT install the most recent versions of the rspec gems?

Comment: This resolved itself in the morning. Apparently the dependency tree was not updated.

Comment: are you sure the dependency tree was updated.  We are still having this issue. Any way to force a resolution?